# 500 Internal Server calling a web service method (C#). How to solve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I call a web service method from a C# application but this call returns a **500 internal server** error after 15 seconds .

Here is the environment:
I have a **IIS server 6.0** on Windows Server 2003. On this server I have a **ASMX** web service page. This server connects to a **SQL Server 2005** (on other machine). So the access to this server is done on the web.config file via a connectionString (`<connectionStrings><add name="MyService" connectionString="Server=SQLSERVER_IP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Uid=MyUid;Pwd=Mypwd;"/></connectionStrings>`).

From my C# application I have this method :

```
private void listObjects()
{
MyData[] datas = MyService.ListMyDatas();
}
```

So calling the method ListMyDatas() returns the following error:

> ```
> <ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: Le client a trouvé 'text/html' comme type de contenu de la réponse, alors qu'il
> ```
>
> attendait 'text/xml'. La demande a échoué avec le message d'erreur :
>   -- 500 Internal Server Error
>
> ## 500 Internal Server Error
>
> An
>   internal server error occurred. Please try again
>   later.
>
> --.
>
> à
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)
>       à System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)
>       à My_tool.com.myapp.MyService.ListMyDatas() dans C:\C#\My tool\Web References\com.myapp\Reference.cs:ligne 1504
>       à My_tool.AppInterface.listObjects() dans C:\C#\My tool\AppInterface.cs:ligne 787    ...
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Web.Services.dll
>
> Additional information: Le client a trouvé 'text/html' comme type de
>   contenu de la réponse, alors qu'il attendait 'text/xml'.

This webservice method was working until today but the amount of data is bigger on the database so I guess that this can be the cause of my problem. Actually it seems that the SQL Server processes the request but I have the error before the request is finished. I think it can be some kind of timeout configuration problem.

Any hint?

Comment: Solve it by understanding that the 500 just says "Something went wrong". Now look into the server to see that _actually_ went wrong.

Comment: To add to @UweKeim's comment.  You should check the event log on the server to see if you can get any more insight into the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved. I defragmented hard disk and reindexed the tables of the database so the queries are faster now and there is no more this 500 internal error.

Answer (score 0):

Now, forgive my best French translation, but I think this message is rather clear:

`Additional information: Le client a trouvé 'text/html' comme type de contenu de la réponse, alors qu'il attendait 'text/xml'.`

So the client tries to fetch using the `text/html` type, but the response is text/xml. You'd probably have change the expected `ContentType` to be `text/xml`. Doesn't seem like it's to do with the mentioned larger dataset.

Comment: The response is html because there was a 500 internal error but obviously the expected type was text/xml. The problem is "what causes this internal error?" so the cause was the requests execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Response code 500 means an exception happened on the server, check your server logs, or if you have access to the code, try to debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the problem was that SQL Server was taking too much time to execute the requests. I defragmented the disk and reindexed all the tables and now it works. So the problem was a timeout problem.